# Want to write to an iframe text input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to fill an input field with data. I have two solutions

```html
<html lang="en" class="iframe">


<body class="task-settings action-plugin-managesieve-save" style="flex-direction:column;display:flex;">
    



    <h1 class="voice">Filter definition</h1>


<div class="formcontent">
    <form name="filterform" class="propform" action="./" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="l8mAHrHDKHak6pD6vevnwrJ58ZHLDoQp"><input type="hidden" name="_task" value="settings"><input type="hidden" name="_action" value="plugin.managesieve-save"><input type="hidden" name="_framed" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="_fid" value="1">

<div class="form-group row"><label for="_join" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Scope</label><div class="col-sm-8"><select name="_join" id="_join" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_join_radio(this.value)">
<option value="allof">matching all of the following rules</option><option value="anyof" selected>matching any of the following rules</option><option value="any">all messages</option></select></div></div><div id="rules">
<fieldset><legend>Rules</legend>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow0">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[0]" id="header0" onchange="rule_header_select(0)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject">Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results" selected>authentication-results</option><option value="received">received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[0]" style="display:none" id="custom_header0"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[0]" style="display:none" id="custom_var0"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[0]" id="rule_op0" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '0')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[0]" c.style.display='block' id="rule_target0">.xyz</textarea>
<div id="rule_size0" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[0]" id="rule_size_op0" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[0]" id="rule_size_i0" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[0]" id="rule_size_item0" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced0" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod0" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[0]" id="rule_mod_op0" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(0)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type0" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[0]" id="rule_mod_type0" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp0" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[0]" id="rule_comp_op0" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans0" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[0]" id="rule_trans_op0" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(0)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[0]" id="rule_trans_type0" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv0" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(0, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd0" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('0'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel0" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('0'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow1">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[1]" id="header1" onchange="rule_header_select(1)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject">Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results">authentication-results</option><option value="received" selected>received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[1]" style="display:none" id="custom_header1"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[1]" style="display:none" id="custom_var1"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[1]" id="rule_op1" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '1')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[1]" c.style.display='block' id="rule_target1">.ru</textarea>
<div id="rule_size1" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[1]" id="rule_size_op1" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[1]" id="rule_size_i1" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[1]" id="rule_size_item1" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced1" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod1" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[1]" id="rule_mod_op1" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(1)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type1" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[1]" id="rule_mod_type1" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp1" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[1]" id="rule_comp_op1" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans1" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[1]" id="rule_trans_op1" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(1)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[1]" id="rule_trans_type1" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv1" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(1, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd1" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('1'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel1" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('1'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow2">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[2]" id="header2" onchange="rule_header_select(2)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject">Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results">authentication-results</option><option value="received" selected>received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[2]" style="display:none" id="custom_header2"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[2]" style="display:none" id="custom_var2"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[2]" id="rule_op2" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '2')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[2]" c.style.display='block' id="rule_target2">.club</textarea>
<div id="rule_size2" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[2]" id="rule_size_op2" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[2]" id="rule_size_i2" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[2]" id="rule_size_item2" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced2" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod2" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[2]" id="rule_mod_op2" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(2)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type2" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[2]" id="rule_mod_type2" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp2" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[2]" id="rule_comp_op2" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans2" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[2]" id="rule_trans_op2" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(2)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[2]" id="rule_trans_type2" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv2" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(2, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd2" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('2'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel2" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('2'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow3">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[3]" id="header3" onchange="rule_header_select(3)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject">Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results" selected>authentication-results</option><option value="received">received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[3]" style="display:none" id="custom_header3"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[3]" style="display:none" id="custom_var3"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[3]" id="rule_op3" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '3')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[3]" c.style.display='block' id="rule_target3">.cam</textarea>
<div id="rule_size3" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[3]" id="rule_size_op3" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[3]" id="rule_size_i3" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[3]" id="rule_size_item3" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced3" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod3" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[3]" id="rule_mod_op3" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(3)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type3" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[3]" id="rule_mod_type3" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp3" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[3]" id="rule_comp_op3" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans3" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[3]" id="rule_trans_op3" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(3)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[3]" id="rule_trans_type3" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv3" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(3, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd3" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('3'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel3" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('3'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow4">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[4]" id="header4" onchange="rule_header_select(4)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject" selected>Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results">authentication-results</option><option value="received">received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[4]" style="display:none" id="custom_header4"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[4]" style="display:none" id="custom_var4"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[4]" id="rule_op4" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '4')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[4]" c.style.display='block' id="rule_target4">abc</textarea>
<div id="rule_size4" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[4]" id="rule_size_op4" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[4]" id="rule_size_i4" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[4]" id="rule_size_item4" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced4" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod4" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[4]" id="rule_mod_op4" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(4)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type4" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[4]" id="rule_mod_type4" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp4" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[4]" id="rule_comp_op4" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans4" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[4]" id="rule_trans_op4" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(4)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[4]" id="rule_trans_type4" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv4" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(4, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd4" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('4'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel4" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('4'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
<div class="rulerow" id="rulerow5">
<table class="compact-table"><tr><td class="rowactions"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_header[5]" id="header5" onchange="rule_header_select(5)" class="custom-select form-control">
<option value="subject" selected>Subject</option><option value="from">From</option><option value="to">To</option><option value="authentication-results">authentication-results</option><option value="received">received</option><option value="return-path">return-path</option><option value="...">...</option><option value="size">Size</option></select><textarea disabled class="" placeholder="Header name" title="Header name" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_header[5]" style="display:none" id="custom_header5"></textarea>
<textarea disabled class="" data-type="list" data-size="15" name="_custom_var[5]" style="display:none" id="custom_var5"></textarea>
</div></td><td class="rowtargets"><div class="flexbox"><select name="_rule_op[5]" id="rule_op5" style="display:inline" class="operator_selector col-6 custom-select" onchange="rule_op_select(this, '5')">
<option value="contains" selected>contains</option><option value="notcontains">not contains</option><option value="is">is equal to</option><option value="notis">is not equal to</option><option value="exists">exists</option><option value="notexists">not exists</option><option value="matches">matches expression</option><option value="notmatches">not matches expression</option></select><textarea class="error" data-type="list" name="_rule_target[5]" c.style.display='inline' id="rule_target5">def</textarea>
<div id="rule_size5" class="input-group" style="display:none"><select name="_rule_size_op[5]" id="rule_size_op5" class="input-group-prepend custom-select">
<option value="over">over</option><option value="under">under</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_size_target[5]" id="rule_size_i5" style="width:auto" class="">
<select name="_rule_size_item[5]" id="rule_size_item5" class="input-group-append custom-select" style="width:auto">
<option value="">B</option><option value="K">KB</option><option value="M">MB</option><option value="G">GB</option></select></div></div>
<div id="rule_advanced5" style="display:none" class="advanced"><div id="rule_mod5" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod[5]" id="rule_mod_op5" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_mod_select(5)">
<option value="">none</option><option value="address">address</option></select></div><div id="rule_mod_type5" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">type:</span></span><select name="_rule_mod_type[5]" id="rule_mod_type5" class="custom-select">
<option value="all">all</option><option value="domain">domain</option><option value="localpart">local part</option></select></div><div id="rule_comp5" class="adv input-group"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">comparator:</span></span><select name="_rule_comp[5]" id="rule_comp_op5" class="custom-select">
<option value="">default</option><option value="i;octet">strict (octet)</option><option value="i;ascii-casemap">case insensitive (ascii-casemap)</option></select></div><div id="rule_trans5" class="adv input-group" style="display:none"><span class="label input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">modifier:</span></span><select name="_rule_trans[5]" id="rule_trans_op5" class="custom-select" onchange="rule_trans_select(5)">
<option value="text">text</option><option value="raw">undecoded (raw)</option><option value="content">content type</option></select><input type="text" name="_rule_trans_type[5]" id="rule_trans_type5" value="" size="20" style="display:none" class=""></div></div></td><td class="rowbuttons"><a href="#" id="ruleadv5" title="Advanced options" onclick="rule_adv_switch(5, this); return false" class="advanced show btn"><span class="inner">Advanced options</span></a><a href="#" id="ruleadd5" title="Add" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruleadd('5'); return false" class="button create add btn"><span class="inner">Add</span></a><a href="#" id="ruledel5" title="Delete" onclick="rcmail.managesieve_ruledel('5'); return false" class="button delete del btn"><span class="inner">Delete</span></a></td></tr></table></div>
</fieldset>

</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

name=“_rule_target[4][]“>
The selector is #rule_target4_list > span > input

Code 1 prints the assigned value for the variable ‘c’ to the console.
Code 1 does not fill the form field with that value.
How can I make it fill the field?

Code 1:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById(‘filter-box’);
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var rulerows = ifrDoc.getElementsByClassName(“rulerow”);
var rowcount = rulerows.length;
var z = rowcount-1;
var c = ifrDoc.getElementById(‘rule_target’+z);
c;
<textarea class=“form-control” data-type=“list” name=“_rule_target[4]” style=“display:none”    id=“rule_target4" disabled>def</textarea>
c.value = ‘def’;
‘def’
```

---

Code 2 prints the value to the console and DOES change the form field.
However, the code uses the specific row number but I want it to use a variable for the row number.
How do I change the Selector from the specific #rule_target4 to the variable #rule_target(z), where z is the last row number(rowcount-1)?

Code 2:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById(‘filter-box’);
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var rulerows = ifrDoc.getElementsByClassName(“rulerow”);
var rowcount = rulerows.length;
var z = rowcount-1;
var c = ifrDoc.querySelector(“#rule_target4_list > span > input”);
c;
<input class=“form-control” type=“text” value=“def” name=“_rule_target[4][]“>
c.value = ‘def’;
‘def’
```

Comment: Please turn off "smart quotes" when posting code. You can't use curly quotes in JavaScript.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML of the iframe, it's impossible to tell why one works but the other doesn't.

Comment: Turned off smart quotes and added edited HTML

Comment: Note: For some reason, the third column of the table, which is the input field containing the entered 'rule-target' data for each row, does not display when the HTML is rendered in the browser.

Comment: You have `style="display: none"` in the textarea, so you won't see it. Add `c.style.display='block'`

Comment: Replaced the display style in the textarea, as suggested. It's not pretty but at least the 3rd column shows. Many thanks for pointing that out! Must view in full page to see it better.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to provide for you to be able to determine how I can solve my problem, i.e., either by filling the form field in my Code1 or by changing the Selector from the specific #rule_target4 to the variable #rule_target(z), where z is the last row number(rowcount-1) in Code2?

Comment: I thought you said that fixing the display solved it.

Comment: Oh no! Fixing the display was   just allowed you to see the fields involved. The My initial problem(s). remain. Sorry for the confusion.